# Django on Heroku: relation "app_label" does not exist

Tags: python, django, heroku, error-handling

I'm trying to deploy my Django app on Heroku. The build is successful, but the deployment fails with `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_label" does not exist`.
I'm deploying directly from GitHub; the repo is [public](https://github.com/stefanbschneider/feelya).

I already looked for advice online and added `try-except` around the `urlpatterns` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53578601/2745116), but it didn't help.
I also have all the migrations committed.
Now I'm not sure what might have caused the problem or how to fix it.

I have successfully deployed another Django and proceeded the same way now, which is why I'm surprised it doesn't work.

I'm trying to connect to the same PostgreSQL DB on Heroku that I use for the other Django app. Is that a problem? Do I need to reconfigure something here? Or do I ever need to run `python manage.py migrate` manually on Heroku? I think this should be taken care of by my [Procfile](https://github.com/stefanbschneider/feelya/blob/main/Procfile#L1).
Any ideas or tips?

I'm using Python 3.8 and Django 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was really with trying to connect to the same PostgreSQL DB that I used for another Django App. I thought there would be just multiple tables in the same DB, but it doesn't work.

I created a new DB and configured the database URL accordingly and it worked.